# block users from retrieving office installation key

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

I am about to give active directory domain users access to a Windows 2008 R2 Remote Desktop Server. The server has Office 2010 installed.

Is it possible for the users to retrieve the installation/product key of Office? If so, what is the best way to avoid that?

Edit: so as I expected your companies keys are on the street when using VLKs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use KMS instead of a VLK for office.

Comment: Use Key Management Services instead of a Volume License Key for Microsoft Office

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the software is called Belarc Advisor and just limit the user (i.e. don't make them admins on the server).  AD should help you with that.